# python syntax error in function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am a beginner to python, and I have a problem when I was trying my new program.
I was trying to define a function to lowercase the inputs, but it only work with integers but int with letters, nor letters, here's what i get:

```
def SomeString(string):
    lowcase = str(string)
    lowcase.lower()
    print lowcase
```

Only integers work, integers with letters or letters wont work:

```
>>> SomeString(TEST0110)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
>>> SomeString(TESTString)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    SomeString(TESTString)
NameError: name 'TESTString' is not defined
```

I tried not to use function to do this and it worked fine:

```
>>> String = "TEST0110"
>>> String.lower()
'test0110'
```

I don't know why it won't work with function, please help.
THanks.

Comment: You should have `lowcase = lowcase.lower()` -- string methods return new strings.  They don't modify the original string.  In fact, there is no way to modify the original string.  python strings are **"immutable"**.

Comment: Not getting your `SyntaxError`. Make sure you include EVERYTHING.

Comment: @JoelCornett, see my answer for a possible reason for the SyntaxError

Comment: One other nit-pick -- CamelCase is typically reserved for classes.  Methods and functions are written in lowercase_with_underscores (by convention) as set up by PEP 8 ( http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ).  It's just a convention, but it never hurts to start off with good style early on.

Answer (score 3):

do this `SomeString("TEST0110")` instead of `SomeString(TEST0110)`

When you write `SomeString(TEST0110)` the code assumes `TEST0110` is a variable,
but in your case it is not

the quotes `""` indicate it is a string

the error `NameError: name 'TESTString' is not defined` means your code is tring to find the variable with name `TESTString`

the function `.lower()` returns the output, which your are not capturing...

Comment: This still doesn't explain the SyntaxError ... (which has me completely confused)

Comment: @Zaia: you should not be getting any syntax error with this code,,, it will throw a `NameError`

Answer (score 3):

`SomeString(TEST0110)` isn't a syntax error, It's a NameError if you don't have a variable called `TEST0110`

`SomeString(0110TEST)` *is* a syntax error

This is because it `0110` is a number, but followed by garbage

`SomeString("TEST0110")` is probably what you mean. It passes a string to the function

If you make sure you always passing a `str` you don't need to call `str()`

```
def SomeString(my_string):
    lowcase = my_string.lower()
    print lowcase
```